# Python syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, operators, new-operator

When I run this code in python, it is giving me a syntax error and highlighting the "l" in the line that I have pointed out. Why is it doing this?

```
from Euler import primeSieve,sumDig

def powerSieve(n):
    powers = []
    primes = primeSieve(100)
    for i in primes:
        j = 2
        while i ** j <= n:
            for k in primes:
                if i == k and i ** j >= 10: powers.append(i ** j)
                else:
                    l = 1
                    while l * (i ** j) <= n:
                        if l * (i ** j) >= 10: powers.append(l * (i ** j)
##THIS LINE             l *= k
            j += 1
    return sorted(set(powers))

from time import clock
start = clock()

print "Answer to PE119 = ",powerSieve(100)

elapsed = clock() - start
print elapsed * 1000,"ms"
```

Comment: You should really spend some more time with your code before you decide to post re: a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a close bracket on the line before. Change this:

```
if l * (i ** j) >= 10: powers.append(l * (i ** j)
```

To this:

```
if l * (i ** j) >= 10: powers.append(l * (i ** j))
```

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Very easy. Thank you. And everyone below too.

Comment: Don't post "thank you" comments, Wait 15 minutes and accept the best answer instead!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the brackets on the preceding line. It should be:

```
powers.append(l * (i ** j))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an if statement above that line, so the above line should end in a colon and the highlighted line should be indented.

Comment: Wrong, look at the `if` statement again.